# Uploadify Flash Safari wrong JSESSIONID

Tags: flash, spring-mvc, uploadify

I came across a strange behavior of the uploadify plugin. The JSESSIONID which is sent to spring controller from the safari browser is wrong. But strangely from Chrome and IE it is correct. Therefore when ever I try to upload from safari I get redirected to the login page.

Please find the request and response from the server.

### Safari

Note: The jsession id **(?jsessionid=936C3165C16C881BA10F16D241D149E1)** part in the request is something I did to tally with the JSSIONID cookie sent in the cookie.

Request

```
POST /webapp/uploadImage.htm?jsessionid=936C3165C16C881BA10F16D241D149E1 HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/*
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------gL6Ef1gL6gL6gL6ei4Ef1GI3ae0GI3
User-Agent: Shockwave Flash
Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
Content-Length: 26764
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Cookie: JSESSIONID=7D8B315F5B9951AABE19FC21347A11A5; s_pers=%20s_fid%3D250B9F5818BE88FF-1CECE4EBA6DDC123%7C1457746300554%3B%20s_vs%3D1%7C1394589700563%3B%20s_nr%3D1394587900595-New%7C1426123900595%3B
```

Response

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=7D8B315F5B9951AABE19FC21347A11A5; Path=/webapp/; HttpOnly
Location: http://127.0.0.1:8080/webapp/login.htm;jsessionid=7D8B315F5B9951AABE19FC21347A11A5
Content-Length: 0
Date: Wed, 12 Mar 2014 04:14:48 GMT
```

### IE and Chrome

Request

```
POST /webapp/uploadImage.htm?jsessionid=478C0E986F2D4E8898C1AB52B4800FE9 HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 173349
Origin: http://127.0.0.1:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.146 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------gL6KM7ei4cH2GI3gL6Ef1Ij5cH2Ef1
Accept: */*
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8080/webapp/create.htm
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: JSESSIONID=478C0E986F2D4E8898C1AB52B4800FE9; csrf=-bmhfmnsiww6p
```

Response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-store
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Wed, 12 Mar 2014 05:01:17 GMT
```

Can anyone please suggest a way to fix this problem?